# How to set the font of text relative to screen resolution

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Algoranker</title>
<style type="text/css">
div.top{
  width:100%;
  height:10%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #474747;
}
p{
  margin-top: 0px;
}
html,body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body >
<div class="top" >
<p>Testing</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to i make the **Testing text in p tag** to vary according to screen resolution i tried using font-size:10%, but not changing, any one suggest me a method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to resize according to the screen width, I'd suggest the `vw` unit.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tey035zv/

Comment: Nice call with the `vw` unit. My only concern would be browser support, which is still a bit weak, especially in IE and mobile.

Comment: It supports IE9 and above and all modern browsers. Another crossbrowser solution will be http://fittextjs.com/ - a js based solution.

Answer (score 1):

hi i would like to suggest you this link to refer just because this supports responsive-ness

i believe to use this

**https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/**

just apply

```css
 font-size : 5vw;
```